# Best Practices: Using Size Classes for Single table view to dual table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, size-classes

I know 'best practices' are a stackoverflow taboo, but i'm giving it a shot anyhow because I think this important and demands a specific answer. Auto layout is new and, with the recently announced iPad side-by-side multitasking, auto layout nuances have never been more important to understand.

**My situation:** My app will have two lists. On the iPhone, they will only be viewed one at a time. I can achieve this:

1. With one ViewController that can toggle between two arrays of list data.
2. With two ViewControllers, each with their own tableView and data
3. With one ViewController and two tables, but one always hidden
4. Better option?

**My specific problem:** On the iPad I want both lists to be shown side by side, simultaneously. Both the iPhone and iPad will run the app only in portrait (landscape will not be supported) I see a few options for supplying the side by side view:

1. Not sure how to make side-by-side work with option #1, except to programmatically add a second table for the iPad layout
2. The two VCs from the iPhone version would appear side by side for the iPad version, using a previously hidden container view to add VC2 to VC1
3. Both tables visible at once
4. Better options?

I would greatly appreciate an answer as to how to achieve this functionality. Although I understand the concepts for each option, I do not understand the specific steps/code, so a thorough explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact scenario in my app and I used Option #2.

For iPad, it'll be using the w-Regular h-Regular size class.
This [site](http://www.jessesquires.com/adaptive-user-interfaces/) has a great visual and explanation of size classes.

- While in Interface Builder, switch to the w-Regular h-Regular size class.

[image: Size Class Selection]

- While in w-Regular h-Regular, drag out a Container View from the Object Library (bottom right corner in Interface Builder) and place it in your view.

[image: Container Selection]

- While in w-Regular h-Regular, set your constraints as you need them to take the Container View into consideration in the new layout.

  - Existing constraints may need to be turned off.  You can do so in the Size Inspector while in the constraint.  Note in the image below that my constraint is installed.  Click the + to the left of the Installed checkmark to *uninstall* it in the w-Regular h-Regular size class.
  - Another way to *uninstall* a constraint is by highlighting the constraint while in the Size Inspector for your screen object and pressing delete.  It doesn't actually delete the constraint, it simply uninstalls it from the current size class.

[image: Installed Constraint]

- Link the VC to the Container View.  ctrl-drag from Container to VC to create an embed segue.  You'll also want to add code to only use this embed segue while on an iPad.  Give the segue an identifier by selecting the segue in IB and going to the Attributes Inspector.  In my example code below I called the segue EmbedSegueName.

  ```
  - (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender  {

      if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && [identifier isEqualToString:@"EmbedSegueName"]) {
          return YES;
      }

      return NO;
  }
  ```
- Don't allow access to the second VC.  I don't know how you're displaying the two different VCs on the iPhone, but in my app I was using `UITTabBarController`.  This is how I removed the extra VC from the iPad's tab bar in my application.

  ```
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

      //  Remove the tab bar item because it will be contained in the iPad's layout.
      //  In this example, it's removing the 2nd tab bar item.
      NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
      [viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:1];
      [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
  }
  ```

**Tip:** If you run into errors running the iPhone version and it's complaining about the container view (even though it's not installed on the iPhone's size classes), try putting the Container View into another view and see if that resolves the issue.

I hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you! This is one of the clearest explanations I've read on any forum.